# How to define a python function

Tags: python, ipython

So I am new to Python and have to take a class in it for college credits. We were given an assignment to do at home (we are allowed to go online for help etc) and part of this involved defining a function. I'm not very good at coding/computers in general and I'm having a lot of difficulty in trying to do so.

How would I go about defining a function so cos(a,b,c) = cos(a - c) - ab? I've tried everything, and I wouldn't be outright asking people for help if I wasn't desperate.

I know that function may seem easy to some but I'm just not good at this at all. 
This is what I tried (don't laugh!)

```
def np.cos(a, b, c):   
"""
Given three variables, rearrange them to create new equation
>>>np.cos(d,e,f)
np.sin(d - f) - e*d
>>>np.cos(1,2,3)
np.cos(1 - 3) - 2*3
"""
if np.cos(a, b, c):
    return np.cos(a - c) - b*a
```

As you can clearly see, I'm not sure what I'm doing. Any advice/tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I think you may be confusing a mathematical function with a method or function as used in imperative programming languages. You should take a step back and start with a Python 101 tutorial that doesn't require any previous programming experience. Eg. https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-computer-science--cs101

Comment: Your indentation is off.

Comment: For starters, every statement in a function has to be indented at least one level (usually 4 spaces by convention). I second the suggestion that you spend a little time and learn Python's basics. _Every_ tutorial you'll find will tell you how to define a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `math.cos()` to determine the `cosine` value of anything in your function.

```
import math 
def cos(a,b,c):
    return math.cos(a-c) - a*b

print cos(1,2,3)
```

Two things to look here:

1. Although I have named my function `cos` to show you the difference between `cos` and `math.cos`, you should name your function to something else like `cosOfthree` to avoid naming conflicts.
2. Always look at your indentation in python code. Instructions inside function definition should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

You can import math and do something like this

```
import math
def trig(a,b,c):
    return math.cos(a-c)-a*b
a,b,c= map(eval,raw_input().split())
trig(a,b,c)
```